# C++ multiple container synchronization in Entity-Component-System compatible with STL

Tags: c++, c++17

I implemented an `Entity` and `ComponentManager< T >` for my new Entity-Component-System (ECS) architecture in my game engine. My older ECS maintained the `Entity` to `Components` mapping on the `Entities` themselves, and the `Component` to `Entity` mappings on the `Components` themselves; all using custom pointer types, since the actual `Entities` and `Components` were stored elsewhere in contiguous memory. This does, however, not result in minimally and optimally packed and aligned `Entities` and `Components`, as is the case for (or at least could be achieved with) my new ECS architecture.

Each `Component` type is managed by a separate container, `ComponentManager< T >`, that encapsulates three separate containers for the following data:

- A contiguous block of memory holding the `Components`. In most cases, `Components` will be processed in front-to-back order without requiring the corresponding `Entities` per frame.
- A contiguous block of memory holding the `Entities`. The `Component` at index `i` in `Components` is associated with the `Entity` at index `i` in `Entities` (i.e. a map where the keys and values are stored separately as opposed to key-value pairs). In rare cases, `Component`-`Entity` pairs are processed in front-to-back order (at most once per `ComponentManager< T >`) per frame.
- An unordered mapping from `Entities` to `Component` indices in `Components`. In rare cases, the `Component` associated with a given `Entity` needs to be retrieved (at most once per `ComponentManager< T >`) per frame.

Since `Components` are mostly processed without requiring the corresponding `Entities`, the `ComponentManager< T >`'s interface provides iterators to `Components` (e.g., support for ranged-based for loop). An additional `RecordIterator< T >` can be used for reordering (e.g., `std::sort`, `std::partition`, etc.) the `Components` of a `ComponentManager< T >`, while reordering the data of the other two containers as well. (Originally, `RecordIterator< T >` and its value type, `Record< T >`, were contained in `ComponentManager< T >` due to their tight connection, but then I could not partially specialize `iterator_traits`.)

I need to put the `swap(mage::Record< T > lhs, mage::Record< T > rhs)` in the `mage` instead of `std` namespace, since both arguments are not passed as references, because `RecordIterator< T >::operator*` returns by value instead of reference. Currently, I do not see a possibility of returning by reference, since `Record< T >`'s do not pre-exist. This, unfortunately, makes the overload of `RecordIterator< T >::operator->` impossible (not sure, however, which STL algorithms actually use this operator anyway).

It is not necessary to update all iterators at once in `RecordIterator< T >`. Only one iterator is updated via the iterator operator overloads. The other iterators are only computed upon swapping. This is much cheaper than retrieving the associated `std::unordered_map< Entity, std::size_t >::iterator` every iterator update (e.g., a completely sorted vector of components does not require any swaps and will thus not perform any `std::unordered_map::operator[]` invocations).

The erase-remove idiom is currently not possible, since associative containers (e.g., `std::unordered_map`) do not support `std::remove/std::remove_if`. I already provide a template function performing both erase and remove/remove_if on a given container, which can thus be overloaded and specialized for a `ContainerManager< T >` to support this as well.

My most important goals are:

- Good performance by exploiting cache coherency, both data and instruction locality, for the most common case of processing the `Components`. (This depends on the actual processing of a `Component` as well, but that is outside the scope of the `ComponentManager< T >`).
- STL compliance: the container and more importantly the associated iterators must be compatible with the functions provided in `<algorithm>` (e.g., work with `std::partition`, `std::sort`, `std::nth_element`, etc.).

I especially like to have some feedback with regard to the latter. General guidelines, best practices? (**Note** that I am less concerned with naming conventions: I use PascalCase for my class and method names, but deviate if similar to or needed for the `std`.)

[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sGjgQ6Xfq4GrVu7I)

**Includes**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
```

**Placeholders**:

```
using U32 = std::uint32_t;

template< typename T >
using AlignedVector = std::vector< T >; // placeholder
```

**Entity**:

```
namespace mage {

    class Entity {

    public:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructors and Destructors
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        constexpr explicit Entity(U32 id = 0u) noexcept
            : m_id(id) {}
        constexpr Entity(const Entity& entity) noexcept = default;
        constexpr Entity(Entity&& entity) noexcept = default;
        ~Entity() = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Assignment Operators
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Entity& operator=(const Entity& entity) noexcept = default;
        Entity& operator=(Entity&& entity) noexcept = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr U32 GetID() const noexcept {
            return m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr explicit operator U32() const noexcept {
            return GetID();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool IsValid() const noexcept {
            return 0u != m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
            return IsValid();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator==(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id == rhs.m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator!=(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id != rhs.m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<=(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id <= rhs.m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>=(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id >= rhs.m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id < rhs.m_id;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>(const Entity& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_id > rhs.m_id;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        std::size_t Hash() const noexcept {
            return std::hash< U32 >()(m_id);
        }

    private:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Variables
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        U32 m_id;
    };

    static_assert(sizeof(U32) == sizeof(Entity));
}

namespace std {

    template<>
    struct hash< mage::Entity > {

        size_t operator()(const mage::Entity& entity) const {
            return entity.Hash();
        }
    };
}
```

**ComponentManager**:

```
namespace mage {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ComponentManager
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template< typename T >
    class ComponentManager {

    public:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Class Member Types
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        using ComponentContainer = AlignedVector< T >;
        using EntityContainer    = AlignedVector< Entity >;
        using MappingContainer   = std::unordered_map< Entity, std::size_t >;

        using value_type
            = typename ComponentContainer::value_type;
        using size_type
            = typename ComponentContainer::size_type;
        using difference_type
            = typename ComponentContainer::difference_type;
        using reference
            = typename ComponentContainer::reference;
        using const_reference
            = typename ComponentContainer::const_reference;
        using pointer
            = typename ComponentContainer::pointer;
        using const_pointer
            = typename ComponentContainer::const_pointer;

        using iterator
            = typename ComponentContainer::iterator;
        using const_iterator
            = typename ComponentContainer::const_iterator;
        using reverse_iterator
            = typename ComponentContainer::reverse_iterator;
        using const_reverse_iterator
            = typename ComponentContainer::const_reverse_iterator;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Friends
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        template< typename U >
        friend class Record;
        template< typename U >
        friend class RecordIterator;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructors and Destructors
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        ComponentManager() = default;
        ComponentManager(const ComponentManager& manager) = default;
        ComponentManager(ComponentManager&& manager) noexcept = default;
        ~ComponentManager() = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Assignment Operators
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        ComponentManager& operator=(const ComponentManager& manager) = default;
        ComponentManager& operator=(ComponentManager&& manager) noexcept = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods: Element access
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        [[nodiscard]]
        bool Contains(Entity entity) const noexcept {
            return m_mapping.find(entity) != m_mapping.cend();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        pointer Get(Entity entity) noexcept {
            if (const auto it = m_mapping.find(entity);
                it != m_mapping.cend()) {

                return &m_components[it->second];
            }

            return nullptr;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_pointer Get(Entity entity) const noexcept {
            if (const auto it = m_mapping.find(entity);
                it != m_mapping.cend()) {

                return &m_components[it->second];
            }

            return nullptr;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reference at(size_type index) {
            return m_components.at(index);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reference at(size_type index) const {
            return m_components.at(index);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reference operator[](size_type index) noexcept {
            return m_components[index];
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reference operator[](size_type index) const noexcept {
            return m_components[index];
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reference front() noexcept {
            return m_components.front();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reference front() const noexcept {
            return m_components.front();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reference back() noexcept {
            return m_components.back();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reference back() const noexcept {
            return m_components.back();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        value_type* data() noexcept {
            return m_components.data();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const value_type* data() const noexcept {
            return m_components.data();
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods: Iterators
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        [[nodiscard]]
        iterator begin() noexcept {
            return m_components.begin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
            return m_components.begin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
            return m_components.cbegin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        iterator end() noexcept {
            return m_components.end();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_iterator end() const noexcept {
            return m_components.end();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
            return m_components.end();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept {
            return m_components.rbegin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept {
            return m_components.rbegin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept {
            return m_components.crbegin();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        reverse_iterator rend() noexcept {
            return m_components.rend();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept {
            return m_components.rend();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept {
            return m_components.crend();
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods: Capacity
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        [[nodiscard]]
        bool empty() const noexcept {
            return m_components.empty();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        size_type size() const noexcept {
            return m_components.size();
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        size_type max_size() const noexcept {
            return m_components.max_size();
        }

        void reserve(size_type new_capacity) {
            m_components.reserve(new_capacity);
            m_entities.reserve(new_capacity);
            m_mapping.reserve(new_capacity);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        size_type capacity() const noexcept {
            return m_components.capacity();
        }

        void shrink_to_fit() {
            m_components.shrink_to_fit();
            m_entities.shrink_to_fit();
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods: Modifiers
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        void clear() noexcept {
            m_components.clear();
            m_entities.clear();
            m_mapping.clear();
        }

        void push_back(Entity entity, const value_type& value) {
            emplace_back(entity, value);
        }

        void push_back(Entity entity, value_type&& value) {
            emplace_back(entity, std::move(value));
        }

        template< typename... ConstructorArgsT  >
        reference emplace_back(Entity entity, ConstructorArgsT&&... args) {
            if (const auto it = m_mapping.find(entity);
                it != m_mapping.cend()) {

                return m_components[it->second];
            }

            m_mapping.emplace(entity, size());
            m_entities.push_back(entity);
            return m_components.emplace_back(
                std::forward< ConstructorArgsT >(args)...);
        }

        void pop_back() {
            m_mapping.erase(m_entities.back());
            m_components.pop_back();
            m_entities.pop_back();
        }

        void swap(ComponentManager& other) noexcept {
            std::swap(m_components, other.m_components);
            std::swap(m_entities,   other.m_entities);
            std::swap(m_mapping,    other.m_mapping);
        }

    // private: commented for std::cout illustration

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Variables
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        AlignedVector< value_type > m_components;

        AlignedVector< Entity > m_entities;

        std::unordered_map< Entity, std::size_t > m_mapping;
    };
```

**Record**:

```
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Record
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template< typename T >
    class Record {

    public:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Class Member Types
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        using ComponentIterator = typename ComponentManager< T >::iterator;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructors and Destructors
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Record() noexcept
            : m_component_it{},
            m_component_manager(nullptr) {}
        explicit Record(ComponentIterator component_it,
                        ComponentManager< T >* component_manager) noexcept
            : m_component_it(std::move(component_it)),
            m_component_manager(component_manager) {}
        Record(const Record& record) noexcept = default;
        Record(Record&& record) noexcept = default;
        ~Record() = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Assignment Operators
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Record& operator=(const Record& record) = delete;
        Record& operator=(Record&& record) noexcept {
            swap(record);
            return *this;
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator==(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it == rhs;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator!=(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it != rhs;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<=(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it <= rhs;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>=(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it >= rhs;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it < rhs;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>(const T& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it > rhs;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator==(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs == *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs != *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator<=(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs <= *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator>=(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs >= *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator<(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs < *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend constexpr bool operator>(const T& lhs, const Record& rhs) noexcept {
            return lhs > *rhs.m_component_it;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator==(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it == *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator!=(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it != *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<=(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it <= *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>=(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it >= *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it < *rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>(const Record& rhs) const noexcept {
            return *m_component_it > *rhs.m_component_it;
        }

        void swap(Record& other) noexcept {
        assert(nullptr != m_component_manager);
        assert(m_component_manager == other.m_component_manager);
        assert(m_component_manager->end() != m_component_it);
        assert(m_component_manager->end() != other.m_component_it);

        const std::size_t index1 = m_component_it - m_component_manager->m_components.begin();
        auto& entity1            = m_component_manager->m_entities[index1];
        auto& mapping1           = m_component_manager->m_mapping[entity1];

        const std::size_t index2 = other.m_component_it - m_component_manager->m_components.begin();
        auto& entity2            = m_component_manager->m_entities[index2];
        auto& mapping2           = m_component_manager->m_mapping[entity2];

        std::swap(*m_component_it, *other.m_component_it);
        std::swap(entity1, entity2);
        std::swap(mapping1, mapping2);
    }

    private:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Variables
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        ComponentIterator m_component_it;
        ComponentManager< T >* m_component_manager;
    };
```

**RecordIterator**:

```
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // RecordIterator
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template< typename T >
    class RecordIterator {

    public:

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Class Member Types
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        using ComponentIterator = typename ComponentManager< T >::iterator;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructors and Destructors
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        RecordIterator() noexcept
            : m_component_it{},
            m_component_manager(nullptr) {}
        explicit RecordIterator(ComponentIterator component_it,
                                ComponentManager< T >* component_manager) noexcept
            : m_component_it(std::move(component_it)), 
            m_component_manager(component_manager) {}
        RecordIterator(const RecordIterator& it) noexcept = default;
        RecordIterator(RecordIterator&& it) noexcept = default;
        ~RecordIterator() = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Assignment Operators
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        RecordIterator& operator=(const RecordIterator& it) noexcept = default;
        RecordIterator& operator=(RecordIterator&& it) noexcept = default;

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Member Methods
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        Record< T > operator*() noexcept {
            return Record< T >(m_component_it, m_component_manager);
        }
        Record< T > operator*() const noexcept {
            return Record< T >(m_component_it, m_component_manager);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        Record< T > operator[](std::size_t n) noexcept {
            return Record< T >(m_component_it + n, m_component_manager);
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        Record< T > operator[](std::size_t n) const noexcept {
            return Record< T >(m_component_it + n, m_component_manager);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        std::size_t operator-(const RecordIterator& it) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it - it.m_component_it;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        const RecordIterator operator+(std::size_t n) const noexcept {
            return RecordIterator(m_component_it + n, m_component_manager);
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        const RecordIterator operator-(std::size_t n) const noexcept {
            return RecordIterator(m_component_it - n, m_component_manager);
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        friend const RecordIterator operator+(std::size_t n, const RecordIterator& it) noexcept {
            return it + n;
        }

        RecordIterator& operator++() noexcept {
            ++m_component_it;
            return *this;
        }
        RecordIterator& operator--() noexcept {
            --m_component_it;
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        friend const RecordIterator operator++(const RecordIterator& it) noexcept {
            return RecordIterator(it.m_component_it + 1u, it.m_component_manager);
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        friend const RecordIterator operator--(const RecordIterator& it) noexcept {
            return RecordIterator(it.m_component_it - 1u, it.m_component_manager);
        }

        RecordIterator& operator+=(std::size_t n) noexcept {
            m_component_it += n;
            return *this;
        }
        RecordIterator& operator-=(std::size_t n) noexcept {
            m_component_it -= n;
            return *this;
        }

        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator==(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it == rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator!=(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it != rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<=(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it <= rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>=(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it >= rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator<(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it < rhs.m_component_it;
        }
        [[nodiscard]]
        constexpr bool operator>(const RecordIterator& rhs) const noexcept {
            return m_component_it > rhs.m_component_it;
        }

    private:

        ComponentIterator m_component_it;
        ComponentManager< T >* m_component_manager;
    };
```

**Miscellaneous**:

```
    template< typename T >
    [[nodiscard]]
    inline RecordIterator< T > RecordBegin(ComponentManager< T >& manager) noexcept {
        return RecordIterator< T >(manager.begin(), &manager);
    }

    template< typename T >
    [[nodiscard]]
    inline RecordIterator< T > RecordEnd(ComponentManager< T >& manager) noexcept {
        return RecordIterator< T >(manager.end(), &manager);
    }

    template< typename T >
    void swap(mage::Record< T > lhs, mage::Record< T > rhs) noexcept {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
}

namespace std {

    template< typename T >
    struct iterator_traits< mage::RecordIterator< T > > {

    public:

        using value_type        = mage::Record< T >;
        using reference_type    = mage::Record< T >&; // not sure?
        using pointer_type      = mage::Record< T >*; // not sure?
        using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}
```

**Main**:

```
int main() {
    mage::ComponentManager< float > manager;
    manager.emplace_back(mage::Entity(5u), 5.0f);
    manager.emplace_back(mage::Entity(4u), 4.0f);
    manager.emplace_back(mage::Entity(3u), 3.0f);
    manager.emplace_back(mage::Entity(2u), 2.0f);
    manager.emplace_back(mage::Entity(1u), 1.0f);

    for (auto& c : manager.m_components) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto& e : manager.m_entities) {
        std::cout << U32(e);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto& [e, i] : manager.m_mapping) {
        std::cout << '(' << U32(e) << "->" << i << ')';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(RecordBegin(manager), RecordEnd(manager));

    for (auto& c : manager.m_components) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto& e : manager.m_entities) {
        std::cout << U32(e);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto& [e, i] : manager.m_mapping) {
        std::cout << '(' << U32(e) << "->" << i << ')';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I guess you've already checked the iterator requirements, but just in case; it's basically implementing everything on this page (and the "named requirements" pages linked from it): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator
- The various `iterator_traits` typedefs are usually defined directly in the iterator class. The unspecialized version of `iterator_traits` just redirects to typedefs defined in the class.
- These types should then be used for the return values of the various iterator functions, e.g.

  ```
  difference_type operator-(const RecordIterator& it) const noexcept {
      return m_component_it - it.m_component_it;
  }
  ```
- Note: this originally returned `std::size_t`. However, the `difference_type` must be signed (`std::ptrdiff_t` is correct). The other mathematical operations have the same issue.
- Unfortunately, we actually need `pointer` and `reference` typedefs, not `pointer_type` and `reference_type`.
- I don't think it's possible to fulfill the exact requirements for the reference type (ForwardIterator requires it to be `T&` or `T const&` where T is `value_type`). Defining it as `Record<T>` should work correctly in most cases though.
- For `pointer`, you might simply define it as `void`, leave the arrow operator undefined, and see if anything breaks. [This answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828507/673679) implies that `reference` and `pointer` aren't used inside the algorithms themselves, so you should be ok. Perhaps someone else with more knowledge can weigh in on this.

---

- Maybe the `Record` class should be lighter weight - handling swap and move only, and providing a means to access the underlying component. At the moment `Record` rather assumes that the components will be able to overload the relevant comparison operator, and that the algorithms using them will only need comparison operators. I could see, e.g. a `LightingComponent` needing to sort lights by distance, or partition them with frustum culling, and might require custom comparators. Being able to access the underlying component from `Record` would allow this, as well as use with a wider range of algorithms.

---

- Is it really necessary to allow an "invalid" Entity to exist?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback! You are absolutely right that `Record` should be more lightweight. Furthermore, invalid `Entities` are not needed (originally, I thought to use invalid Entities for my own garbage collection, but this flagging should be handled by the `Components` instead. I tried to integrate  all of this feedback in the following [Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7X8hKdj4E0qBWsiM).

Comment: Defining the various iterator_traits typedefs in the iterator class itself (and the fact that the std can handle this) is wonderful, since this allows to move `Record` and `RecordIterator` back to `ComponentManager`. Similarly, for the `RecordBegin` and `RecordEnd` functions, which is more convenient for a user.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latter is still not possible in a general way (i.e. template) for due to the `swap`. [Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gexh0T3mW0ftthXB) SFINAE can probably provide a way around this (i.e. additional unique typedef inside record).

Comment: I found a solution for the latter using `inline friend`: [Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ceH7si8X1pUWRJ1v)